# OnCompleted is not fired if CancellationDisposable is used with MultiCast

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I implemented an observable using `Observable.Create` that uses a `CancellationDisposable`.
As I want to share the observable after creation I use `Publish` and later `Connect`.
If the disposable returned by `Connect` is disposed the `CancellationDisposable` is disposed too and an `OperationCancelledException` is thrown.
The problem is that the observer `o1` never gets informed of the exception.
Why does this happen and how can I adept the code to use a `CancellationDisposable` and `Publish` in combination?

```
var obs = Observable.Create<int>(
            observer =>
                {
                    var cancel = new CancellationDisposable();
                    var scheduler = Scheduler.Default.Schedule(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                observer.OnNext(1);
                                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                                cancel.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                observer.OnNext(2);

                                observer.OnCompleted();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                observer.OnError(ex);
                            }
                        });
                    return new CompositeDisposable(cancel, scheduler);
                })
            .ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
            .Publish();

        var o1 = obs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Next: {0}", x), x => Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", x), () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));

        var connection = obs.Connect();

        Console.WriteLine("Press key to cancel");
        Console.ReadLine();

        connection.Dispose();

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output if one presses Enter immediately:

```
Press key to cancel
Next: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disposing the connection disposes all subscriptions (internally).  This is the cancellation model of Rx.  When a subscription is disposed, the observer no longer receives notifications of any kind.

See §4.4 in the [Rx Design Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219) document.

If you want to receive a notification when your observer is cancelled, then use the [Finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212133(v=vs.103).aspx) operator.  Note that it applies to termination in general, so your action is invoked upon completion or failure as well.

```
var o1 = obs.Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Terminated")).Subscribe(...);
```

**Update:**

Reading over my answer I realized that I wasn't entirely clear.  The `Finally` operator is only invoked when you dispose of the subscription yourself.  Disposing the connection only disposes of the internal subscriptions to the published observable, leaving your subscriptions "active".  The reason for this is because you can always reconnect the published observable and your subscriptions will continue to receive notifications.  Thus, `o1` wasn't actually cancelled at all.

<strike>Furthermore, `OnCompleted` could not be called anyway, since then it would be possible for it to be called multiple times on the same subscription by simply reconnecting the observable, which of course breaks the Rx Grammar.  See §4.1 in the Rx Design Guidelines.</strike>

**Update 2:**

As mentioned in the comments, although `OnCompleted` isn't called upon cancellation, it is called when the observable successfully terminates; however, observers will no longer receive any notifications in the future (to satisfy the Rx Grammar), even upon subsequent reconnects.  Furthermore, all `Finally` operators will have executed because the sequence has terminated.

**Update 3: Answer**

It's certainly possible to have `OnCompleted` called on every observer upon cancellation of a connectable observable, though I wouldn't recommend this because it's deeply strange, as it goes against the grain in Rx, but alas I must provide it to technically answer the original question.  The key to this solution is the use of a `Subject<T>` along with a `Finally` operator inserted before the call to `Publish`.

Note that I've changed the code slightly to use an [Async Iterator](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/async-iterators.aspx) and to remove the bad error handling (see note below).

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RxLabs.Net45
{
  class PublishFinallyLab
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      var obsOrCancellation = new Subject<int>();

      var obs = Observable.Create<int>(
            async (observer, cancel) =>
            {
              observer.OnNext(1);

              await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), cancel).ConfigureAwait(false);

              if (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
              {
                observer.OnNext(2);
              }
            })
            .Finally(obsOrCancellation.OnCompleted)
            .Publish();

      obs.Subscribe(obsOrCancellation);

      var o1 = obsOrCancellation
            .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Finally!"))
            .Subscribe(
              x => Console.WriteLine("Next: {0}", x),
              ex => Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex),
              () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));

      do
      {
        using (var connection = obs.Connect())
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Press any key to cancel.");
          Console.ReadKey();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
      while (true);
    }
  }
}
```

--

On an unrelated though important note, it's an anti-pattern to catch exceptions thrown by observers.  Don't do it.  You should remove the `try..catch` entirely.  You have no code in your observable calling into non-observer code that may throw, thus you should not be calling `OnError` at all.

Comment: Hi Dave. Thanks a lot for the link to the design guidelines and the clarification regarding the semantics of Publish, Connect and disposing a connection. Concerning `OnCompleted`: It can be called and the `o1` gets informed about completion. If I reconnect again `o1` does not get any further notifications because the observable completed. At least that's what I could observe using a small example.
How would you implement an observable that can be canceled but also shared among several subscribers using `Publish`?

Comment: Yes, you're correct that OnCompleted is called, though not for cancellation.  I've edited my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Assuming that you still want `OnCompleted` to be called on each observer upon disposing of the published connection, I'd say you may have to collect the subscriptions into a disposable manually.  There are no Rx operators that aggregate subscriptions on published observables and tie them to the lifetime of the connection.  I'll update my answer with an example in a moment.